# How to parse out date from non standard date string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date that is returned in this string format from moment.js for a calendar app.

[image]

> Fri Jun 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

How can i parse this string back into '2017-06-16', using moment to backtrack specifies this is an invalid input. Using it as an instance of new Date() returns to me an incorrect date.

```
var check = moment('Fri Jun 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)', 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var month = check.format('M');
var day   = check.format('D');
var year  = check.format('YYYY');

console.log(month, day, year);
//-->invalid date
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t89apndd/

Comment: Check moment.js: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/

Comment: That console output does not show a string. It show an object property named `date` whose value is a Moment object. It looks like the `_d` property is a Date object (*presented* as "Fri Jun ..." so you can read it, for debugging purposes). If it were a string it would be displayed wrapped in quotation marks.

Comment: @JordanRunning totally agree with you, the OP is logging a moment object. `_d` is a private property for internal use and it should not be used. Moment has the [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to show string value of a moment object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You don't need `moment.js`.

Just use the native [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.

```js
const date = new Date('Fri Jun 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)');
const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(day, month, year);
```

And if you need to convert an existing moment.js date:

```js
const momentDate = ...;//insert your moment.js date here
const date = new Date(momentDate._i);
const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(day, month, year);
```

Comment: "And if you need to convert an existing moment.js date..." Huh? Why access a "private" property (`_i`) when you can use Moment's built-in [`toDate`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method?

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with Jordan Running's comment

> That console output does not show a string. It show an object property named date whose value is a Moment object

Since you already have a moment object (your `date` var), you can simply use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show moment value in the format you prefer.

In your case you can do:

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Here a live sample:

```js
var date = moment([2017, 5, 16]);
console.log(date); // Print moment object (like the one provided in the question)
console.log(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // Print string output of format (in the desired format)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you *really* want `moment.js`...

```js
var check = moment(new Date('Fri Jun 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'));

var month = check.format('M');
var day   = check.format('D');
var year  = check.format('YYYY');

console.log(month, day, year);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to your dump of date, the object show me the attribute

```
_isValid: false
```

check the fiddle and console log
https://jsfiddle.net/s6x87u1p/